# AWS Lambda (python): Pass list of file paths and execute each file as a separate lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, concurrency, aws-lambda

I have one python lambda function that will list each file in an S3 bucket (code below).  What I am not clear on how to do is pass `each file object` to another lambda function as an input and have separate executions.  The goal is to have `x` number of files in the list to create `x` number of the second lambdas to execute concurrently (i.e. if there are 20 files in the list, then execute the second lambda with 20 executions with each file passed to the lambda function respectively).  The file will be used in the second lambda function for a join in Pandas.

Really appreciate any help!

## List of files (lambda 1)

```
import boto3

#Start session with Profile
session = 
boto3.session.Session(profile_name='<security_token_service_profile>')

client = session.client('s3') #low-level functional API
resource = session.resource('s3') #high-level object-oriented API

#State S3 bucket
my_bucket = resource.Bucket('<bucket>') #subsitute this for your s3 bucket name. 

#List all files
files = list(my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='<path_to_file>'))

print(files)
```

Comment: It looks like you already have the list of objects, so just iterate over that list and call lambda.invoke async(FunctionName, InvokeArgs) for each object, providing the relevant information about the S3 object to the invoked Lambda function through InvokeArgs. Note that lambda = session.client('lambda') in this case.

Comment: Thank you @jarmod!  Answer that worked for me is below

Comment: Yes, not sure why I suggested the deprecated async variant, but the regular client.invoke(FunctionName, InvocationType='Event', Payload) is the best option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @jarmod!  That worked.  For those who might need this in the future, my lambda script above has been modified as follows:

```
import boto3
import json

print('[INFO]  Loading Function')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    print("[INFO]  Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))

    #Start session with region details for authentication
    session = boto3.session.Session(region_name='<region>')
    client = session.client('s3') #low-level functional API
    resource = session.resource('s3') #high-level object-oriented API

    #Identify S3 bucket
    my_bucket = resource.Bucket('<bucket>') #subsitute this for your s3 bucket name. 

    #List all files
    files = list(my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='<file_path>'))

    for file in files:
        payload = json.dumps({"key": file.key})
        print(payload)
        client_lambda = session.client('lambda')
        client_lambda.invoke(
            FunctionName='<lambda_function_name_to_call>',
            InvocationType='Event',
            LogType='None',
            Payload=payload
        )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    lambda_handler()`
```